# how to remove query parameter in URL after submitting in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have this submit handler

```js
const handleComment = async () => {
  try {
    axios.post(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post/${id}/comments`,
      {
        text: text,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
    navigate(`/post/${id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

which I use here

```js
<Form onSubmit={handleComment}>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3 mt-2">
    <Form.Label>Create An Comment</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      as="textarea"
      placeholder="Enter Comment"
      name="text"
      maxLength={255}
      onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
    />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value={userId} />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={post.id} />
  </Form.Group>
  <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
</Form>
```

The expected result is `http://localhost:5173/post/2` but I'm getting `http://localhost:5173/post/2?text=test&user_id=2&post_id=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `event` from the `onSubmit` handler to prevent the default action from happening.

You also might want to use `post.id` instead of `id` to pass to the url's

```js
const handleComment = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    axios.post(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post/${post.id}/comments`,
      {
        text: text,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
    navigate(`/post/${post.id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```